# Sending webpages over bluetooth

Tags: android, webview, bluetooth

I am using this tutorial

[http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html.](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html)

I want to access the internet via one android phone and then send it to other phone over bluetooth. **Though the webpage is displayed really slowly and the webpage is not displayed correctly.** I tried sending the it line-by-line and loading it into webview on line-by-line basis and then loading it to webview as whole chunk using StringBuilder, tried sending it as a whole chunk and loading as a chunk by StringBuilder. Also I have provided all the permissions.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I am accessing the internet via

```
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.sheldonbrown.com/web_sample1.html"); 
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while (( line = in.readLine())!= null) {
    line = in.readLine();
    sendMessage(line);
```

and then retrieve it on the other end and load it webview.

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
              String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
               add = readMessage + add;
                    try {
        mWebView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(add,"utf-8").replaceAll("\\+"," "),
                            "text/html", "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
               break;
```

Where add is String add= "";

Comment: what is the problem ?where are you stuck.

Comment: The problem being the webpages are being uploaded in webview really slowly (the application doesnt responds sometimes) though the data is sent in no matter of time when checked in bluetooth chat application. If the webpage is big all of the data is not shown.

Comment: use spp for sending data .its used for serial transfer...

Answer (score 0):

You have just send html code to another phone, but not image/css/js.
So if you need show as normal, please also send the these files.

But i don't think this is a good way, waybe PAN is more better.

Comment: Please include this as comment.